# mobile responsive failed in real device

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, owl-carousel

This is my website: http://styles.my/widget_stylescopy/mstar_v2/scheduler/mstar.php.

Everything is fine in Chrome.
But it doesn't work in Chrome emulator nor in real mobile device.

I use http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#demo for the slider, but the slider itself is responsive. I wonder what is wrong. I'm sure I didn't missed declared owl carousel's setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one main difference between your website and the owlgraphic site, from what I can see.

Your slider is implemented correctly, but the reason it doesn't work on mobile / chrome emulator is you need to add a meta tag to your `head`. This one is ripped straight from Owl Carousel:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: you made my day! I'm so careless to use bootstrap. I should have start with bootstrap template.. TQ VERY MUCH @Adam!

Answer (score 0):

You should ask specific question. We're not "my code didn't work and I don't know why fixer".

No one understand your code more than you.